# Lenovo Fn shortcuts on i3

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, lenovo, thinkpad, i3-wm

I'm using *Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS* on my *Lenovo Thinkpad E590* and I'm actually trying to add the Lenovo shortcuts (like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to mute, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to decrease the screen's brightness, etc.)

Let's take the example of decreasing the screen brightness, which is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on the standard desktop of Ubuntu (which is Unity, right ?)

This is basically what every solution found on the internet told me to do:

- Use xev to get the name of the key.

So **<kbd>Fn</kbd> = XF86WakeUp** and **<kbd>F5</kbd> (when <kbd>Fn</kbd> is pressed) = XF86MonBrightnessDown**.

Then edit the `~/.config/i3/config` file by adding this:

```
bindsym XF86WakeUp+XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 10 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86WakeUp+XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 10 # decrease screen brightness
```

But this doesn't work after reloading and rebooting my i3. I don't had any error.
Same for the volume control.

```
bindsym XF86WakeUp+XF86AudioUpperVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 +2% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86WakeUp+XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 -2% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86WakeUp+XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle # mute sound
```

Does someone knows where the problem is? Because I don't find it.
Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Isn't it easier to add the shortcuts of System Preferences > Keyboard? And it doesn't recognize the key combination you press, let the xmodmap or something similar to do the work?

Comment: Sir, the system understands when Fn+F5 is pressed X86MonBrightnessDown, so it should be 'bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -10 # decrease screen brightness' and 'killall -SIGUSR1 i3status' to take effect immediately. I am not sure because I don't have the exact same laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SadaharuWakisaka explained his/her comment:

> Sir, the system understands when Fn+F5 is pressed X86MonBrightnessDown, so it should be 'bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -10 # decrease screen brightness' and 'killall -SIGUSR1 i3status' to take effect immediately. I am not sure because I don't have the exact same laptop.

My keybinding wasn't completly correct as well so this worked for me:

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%  # volume increase
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%
  #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle  # mute sound
bindsym XF86AudioMicMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ toggle  # mute mic
```